# Notepad Path in VS2008

Tags: c#, notepad

In my application, I have defined the following:

`public static readonly string NOTEPAD = "%windir%\\notepad.exe";`

I can type in the text value of NOTEPAD into the Run command on my Win7 machine, and Notepad will open.

However, from within my Visual Studio C# project, the Write Line routine will fire every time:

```
  if (!File.Exists(NOTEPAD)) {
    Console.WriteLine("File Not Found: " + NOTEPAD);
  }
```

Does Visual Studio not understand `%windir%`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of expanding the variable manually as suggested by the other answers so far, you can have the Environment class do this for you just like the `Run` command does:

```
if (!File.Exists(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(NOTEPAD))) {
  Console.WriteLine("File Not Found: " + NOTEPAD);
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx

Comment: +1 For keeping it closely relevant to the OP's example code, and providing a fix therein.

Comment: I actually liked this answer better, so I changed my mark.  

All answers seem to work, though.

Comment: Apart from the fact that NOTEPAD is not a string, Windows 10 doesn't have an environment variable NOTEPAD. Of course you could set the environment, but do you want to let your program depend on non-standard environment variables?

Comment: @HaraldDutch, please read the very first sentence of the question: "In my application, I have defined the following: ..."

Answer (score 2):

When looking on my windows XP box, the location of notepad is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe
```

Not:

```
%windir%\notepad.exe
```

You also need to make sure that these environment variables are resolved correctly - use [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx) and [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781134.aspx) to build up the correct path:

```
string root = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot");
string path = Path.Combine(root, "system32", "notepad.exe");
```

Comment: On mine it's in C:\WINDOWS as well as C:\WINDOWS\system32. I checked another box and it's in both places as well.

Comment: @dcp - Fair enough. I think MS decided on placing it in two locations for some versions. But for server 2008 it is only in system32 - see this blog post from Raymond Chen: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/01/28/9954432.aspx

Comment: I'm curious if "system32" changes on 64-bit systems or if it is case sensitive. I had hard coding strings.

Comment: @jp2code - Just checked my Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit virtual machine, and "system32" is there, live and kicking with "notepad.exe" in place...

Answer (score 1):

Just have a closer Look at the Class Environment.  The Environment Variable is SystemRoot, so you can use
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") (or something like that)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx

The console "Resolves" the %windir% environment variable to the correct path.  You need to use the above function to do the same within your application.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir")`;

So you could declare it like this:

```
public static readonly string NOTEPAD = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + "\\notepad.exe";
```